# User JS read out by webpage JS

Tags: javascript, html, userjs

Currently I add some functionality to webpages via UserJS in Opera. I was wondering if the webpage designer could see what javascript actions I'm doing in my UserJS on his webpage (e.g. via javascript)?

Is this possible? I think it doesn't because the UserJS gets executed first and isn't really 'added' to the page. I'd like to be sure, hence the question.

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by "read out".

Comment: textual. If I add a function x to element z, can the webdesigner see the function x and examine the code in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  `user.js` scripts are local and only executed on the system.

If you want your web designer to have the same function, you'd need to send them your script files and have them use Opera.